# match/search dict keys in elements of a list

Tags: python

I have a dictionary,

```
dct = {'slab1': {'name':'myn1', 'age':20}, 'slab2':{'name':'myn2','age':200}}
lst = {'/store/dir1/dir_slab1/tindy', '/store/dir2/dirslab2_fine/tunka','/store/dir1/dirslab3/lunku'}
```

How can I search for 'slab1', 'slab2' which are the keys of the dictionary in the list elements ? If there is a match, I would like to print the matched element and the 'age' from the dictionary. So, in the above example, I should get something like :

```
  '/store/dir1/dir_slab1/tindy', 20
  '/store/dir2/dirslab2_fine/tunka', 200
```

Thanks for any suggestion

Comment: Your second variable named `list` is actually a `set`.  (also, it's not a good idea to name variables `list`, `dict`, etc).

Comment: You shouldn't use dict and list as variable names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
>>> dct = {'slab1': {'name':'myn1', 'age':20}, 'slab2':{'name':'myn2','age':200}}
>>> lst = {'/store/dir1/dir_slab1/tindy', '/store/dir2/dirslab2_fine/tunka','/store/dir1/dirslab3/lunku'}
>>> for item in lst:
...    for pattern in dct:
...       if pattern in item:
...           print "%s, %s" % (item, dct[pattern]["age"])
... 
/store/dir1/dir_slab1/tindy, 20
/store/dir2/dirslab2_fine/tunka, 200
```

You can also use list comprehension notation to get pairs:

```
>>> [(item, dct[pattern]["age"]) for item in lst for pattern in dct if pattern in item]
[('/store/dir1/dir_slab1/tindy', 20), ('/store/dir2/dirslab2_fine/tunka', 200)]
```

P.S. There are some misunderstandings in your question (eg, `list` variable is not a list), but solution should look like this.

Comment: Thanks. This worked fine. Those dict and list are for example purpose. Sorry for putting it this way. I will edit them...